# regex for extracting all urls from dict like string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-2.7, list-comprehension

**here is my string from which i have to extract urls**

```
s = "'0352442':{url:'https://www.riteaid.com/shop/nexium-24hr-42-ct-capsules-0352442'},'0370009':{url:'https://www.riteaid.com/shop/rite-aid-pharmacy-epsom-salt-first-aid-6-lb-2-72-kg-0370009'},'0303249':{url:'https://www.riteaid.com/shop/huggies-natural-care-unscented-baby-wipes-soft-pack-56-count-0303249'},'0398568':{url:'https://www.riteaid.com/shop/rite-aid-sterile-pads-4-x4-25-ea-0398568'},}"
```

my attempted code till now prints only

```
urls = re.findall('https?://(?:[-\w.]|(?:%[\da-fA-F]{2}))+', s)
```

but it prints only repetition of this url

```
    ['https://www.riteaid.com']
```

Comment: You can use json to parse the dict.

Comment: i have to parse using regex ,thats mandatory need help of regex expert

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned dict like string you have to use regex for your particular case this can be used.

```
s = "'0352442':{url:'https://www.riteaid.com/shop/nexium-24hr-42-ct-capsules-0352442'},'0370009':{url:'https://www.riteaid.com/shop/rite-aid-pharmacy-epsom-salt-first-aid-6-lb-2-72-kg-0370009'},'0303249':{url:'https://www.riteaid.com/shop/huggies-natural-care-unscented-baby-wipes-soft-pack-56-count-0303249'},'0398568':{url:'https://www.riteaid.com/shop/rite-aid-sterile-pads-4-x4-25-ea-0398568'},}"

urls = re.findall(r"url:'(https?://.*?)'}", s)

result:
['https://www.riteaid.com/shop/nexium-24hr-42-ct-capsules-0352442',
 'https://www.riteaid.com/shop/rite-aid-pharmacy-epsom-salt-first-aid-6-lb-2-72-kg-0370009',
 'https://www.riteaid.com/shop/huggies-natural-care-unscented-baby-wipes-soft-pack-56-count-0303249',
 'https://www.riteaid.com/shop/rite-aid-sterile-pads-4-x4-25-ea-0398568']
```

**Explanation**

**url:'(http**: literal string

**s?**: optional literal character "s"

**.*?**: non greedy any character.

**'}:**: literal string

Comment: gottcha thanxxx

Comment: You can accept the answer if this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you must use a regex for your current example to match between `{url:'` and `'}` you could use a positive [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?<=` and a positive lookahead `(?=` and match the url using a negated character class `[^']+` which matches not a `'` one or more times.

[`(?<={url:')[^']+(?='})`](https://regex101.com/r/IAq52j/1/)

[Demo](http://rextester.com/JFCO70914)

You can also be less restrictive for your example data and leave out the leading `{` and trailing `}`:

[`(?<=url:')[^']+(?=')`](https://regex101.com/r/IAq52j/2)